# Should edits for double spaces be allowed?

Tags: discussion, edits, whitespace

I just had a [post edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330084/196058) for a questionable grammatical 'thingie' and for double spacing after a period/full stop.  That's right.  Like this.  See?  No, you can't!  Unless I do this.  There it is.

Listen, I don't care if you want to show you are cool or ergonomic by using single spaces; but is this really something that should be a viable and approvable edit?  Smacks of Wikipedia-type editorial activity that will eventually send many of us running for the hills of ... of I don't know where else.

And listen, I don't *really* care that much, but it does seem bizarre, so I submit that perhaps we should gently suggest such behavior is too finicky.

Especially since apparently the double spaces get turned into single spaces anyway, it seems?  This is not a dup of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263575/double-space-after-period-obsolete).  See [this amusing article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2018/05/04/one-space-between-each-sentence-they-said-science-just-proved-them-wrong-2/) for background.

Comment: Bonus points to the person who catches the Easter egg in this question.

Answer (score 11):

Your post got edited to correct the grammar in it. While the editor was there, they happened to also knock off a spare space - those double-spaces don't get rendered when the Markdown gets converted to HTML. *In general*, the post author's style should be left alone, and edits that *solely* do things like this (see: en-GB vs en-US edits) are strongly discouraged... when it's something as minor as this, it's not worth the effort in complaining.

If you really feel it makes a difference... you can always edit your extra space back in.

Comment: True.  But I don't think that "a community" versus "community" is necessarily incorrect grammar.  A community is a thing.

Comment: More to the point, I don't actually care, but I do care about people who make completely inconsequential edits, because that really ruins the point of the site, which is useful information.  So that is why I complain.

Comment: "Getting community started" is incorrect grammar. "Getting _a_ community started" is correct grammar. Minor, yes - inconsequential, no. The fact that your extra space was also removed is orthogonal, and can be reversed as an authorial style choice.

Comment: Wait, what?  Both of these are fine.  "Building community" is a very common phrase (actually, *too* common) in many settings.

Comment: Certainly not one I've come across without it being corrected. Building community _what_, it implies? Building community spirit, sure, or building community consensus, etc - but not just building community. More to the point - building _a_ community is certainly the more common and more well understood form - reading "building community" takes a moment to parse; reading it with the article is obvious. It follows that editing it to the latter form is an improvement - if not in grammar, then in readability.

Comment: I'm unsure whether we've built community together here or not, but [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=building+community%2C+building+a+community&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuilding%20community%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuilding%20a%20community%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbuilding%20community%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuilding%20a%20community%3B%2Cc0) seems to support that this isn't something I'm making up.  Anyway, all trivialities ... I just hope new users don't get turned off by this sort of unnecessary editing.

Comment: @kcrisman "Building community" is fine. "Building community started" is not.

Comment: ?  "Building a community started" isn't correct either, so that is a red herring.  "Getting community going" seems fine to me, but I won't bother credentialing myself.

Comment: Inter alia, I'm sort of impressed by how many downvotes I'm getting on this question - clearly it has struck a chord with people who would make this kind of edit.  I suppose I could go for the "Peer Pressure" badge, but I'm actually more proud of the downvotes.

Comment: @kcrisman you didn't say "building community, though. You said "getting community."

Comment: I think we are agreeing, because I said "getting community going".  I found "building community" to be something more people might have heard said, so I used that as an example in these (now very extended) comments.

Comment: Perhaps if one thought of "community" as a collective plural we could all agree.  Otherwise one could diagram the sentence where "these" have "a community", which is a little strange given that there are multiple communities, though each of them will have community ... <gives up trying to explain>